# Crash course to understand the language of "vector bundles"

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, manifolds

I am currently following a course which is on analysis on manifolds. The problem is that while I have strong knowledge on topics of analysis (functional, harmonic, etcetera), I know almost nothing regarding the theory of manifolds. This is obviously quite problematic.

Thus far I have read the first two dozen or so pages of Lee's 'Introduction to Smooth Manifolds' and thereby became acquainted with charts, atlases et al. But I would really like to know if there is a fast way for me to acquire this vector bundle language with its "fibres", "sections", "densities", "forms" et al after which I can rely on my intuition?

Comment: That's all in Lee, too.

Comment: @MikeMiller But Lee's book is huge; not exactly a "crash course".

Comment: You might consider Hatcher's free book "Vector Bundles and K-theory." As with anything Hatcher writes, it is high quality, and it gives a fast overview of the basics of vector bundles: https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf

Comment: I have found [Differential Geometry: Bundles, Connections, Metric and Curvature](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Differential-Geometry-Connections-Curvature-Mathematics/dp/0199605874) by Clifford Taubes useful.He finishes with the necessary bundle structure within the first 70 pages.

Comment: take a promenade around the wikipedia ad hoc entries